# VLC streaming convert error message

Tags: vlc-media-player

I'm trying to convert a video from youtube using vlc. This used to work well, but lately, I've been getting this error message--

> Your input can't be opened:
>   VLC is unable to open the MRL 'http://o-o.preferred.ams03s07.v4.lscache7.c.youtube.com /videoplayback?sparams=id%2Cexpire%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass&itag=37&ip=77.0.0.0&>signature=84D1ECDF392C933CF8DECD454B4AFC83DE86B467.C821C36A0B39C73587A6EE46656BD7065688E5AB&sver=3&ratebypass=yes&expire=1307671200&key=yt1&ipbits=8&id=a9d0d5b45bc9c147'. Check the log for details.

What should I do?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the log for details? What were the details?

Comment: You see that there is a space in your URL?